# Unable to login to facebook from webview

Tags: android, webview

Hi guys I am not Unable to login to facebook from webview.
After logging in, it always shows `You must login first.` as screenshot attached. Anybody has any ideas on this please?

```
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
settings.domStorageEnabled = true
settings.userAgentString = UrlRepositoryImpl.USER_AGENT
settings.useWideViewPort = true
settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webChromeClient = new obj...
webViewClient = new obj...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook login in webviews is deprecated.Beginning October 5, 2021, Facebook Login was no longer support using Android embedded browsers (WebViews) for logging in users.

Check this out : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews